# How to go about managing a client's hosting and infrastructure

Tags: software-development, freelancing, consulting

I'm just getting into freelancing!

I see that a lot of clients are mom & pops stores. Often, they'll want a dev to set them up with a website. Simple static marketing pages can easily be done with a service like Wix, Wordpress, etc.

More complex features may actually require renting out server space or using some platform like AWS or Heroku.

Often, these people will be non-technical and will refer to the dev they hire to set all this up.

My question is...how is the business portion handled. Like..should the hired dev

1. Setup the AWS, Wordpress, Colo accounts for the client (requiring them to obtain client's sensitive info)
2. Educate client on why only they should set this up but them guide them on it
3. Dev has their own dedicated AWS, Wordpress account where they just add servers,etc based on when they add clients and then bill clients for this.

Surely each has their own benefits and caveats and cases are probably subjective contingent on project and size of client.

This is a kind of question I've always wondered about.

For 1&2..caveats can be client doesn't know what they're getting into and could get hit with a huge bill that they don't understand.

For 3...caveat is that dev may have to temporarily cover client's costs or risk never being reimbursed.

I would think #2 is probably the right answer. Sounds like simple WP, Wix sites usually have a pretty good cost estimate and that clients will know roughly what they will be paying. Also, I would imagine these services would be easy to setup for a small non-technical business as it's made for that exact reason.

For more complex platforms and apps that would require a VPC or similar...I'd imagine these clients would need the resources to even consider something like this before even inquiring dev for an app.

Also, if Dev is getting access to a client's server,etc..What's the desired pattern for getting secure access? I see a lot of platforms allow businesses to invite a collaborator. This makes most sense as opposed to giving root pwd to dev or something.

**Update:** Here are some specifics on current prospect.
I've designed a system using Twilio in which a customer can call the client's phone#...and then receive an automated MMS about the business' location,hours,etc..

I've actually already finished this and my intent was to demo it to client and then name my price.

They are very non-technical and it seems evident they don't want to register their own Twilio account and whatnot.

Twilio has a prepaid option. I'm thinking I can have them top my account off with their estimated monthly (maybe even annual need). This will vary on how many calls they think they'll get.

Given all this..I think #3 is a fine solution. It makes it more expendable should I offer same solution for other clients too.

One caveat here is if something were to happen to me. What options would the client have then? Might be something I'd have to work out between Twilio and business, any insights?

Comment: As a freelancer, it's your responsibility to estimate and quote development cost, development time,  and operating costs when bidding for the job. If you underestimate, you get a bad reputation. If you overestimate, you may lose contracts to someone who quotes a more accurate number. Learn to quote accurately. Initially, you may want to err in the conservative side, and may want to quote fixed cost and eat the loss if you run over.

Comment: Secure access needs to be worked out with your client.

Comment: There is a freelancing stack which this is better suited to.

Comment: If you just want to do the development and the initial setup you can try to partner with a company that is a cloud resseller, they are used to handle the sensitive informations, be careful that the consumption does not grow unnoticed, handle the long term commercial relationship. And it may even reassure your customer that even if you disapear there's a company they can contact if needed.

Comment: I've done an iOS app through a W9. When I was a student and it was small hourly rate followed by fixed cost once I was able to charge more

Comment: Another aspect of doing business with small businesses is that many of them want something, but do not have the funds or the will to spend to get what they really need. If you really want to sell to them, often selling a package that they can customize is the only way to go (see QuickBooks for example) and hope to sell many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I feel I can give some insight here as my professional experience has mostly been in the Web hosting space.

I've seen many Devs/freelancers run into this issue.

From what I've seen - it really comes down to what are you offering the Client.

Let me explain - some Devs will offer the client a fully Managed solution - they setup the AWS resources, they manage it etc. in return, they charge the customer an ongoing fee (as well as passing on the cost(s) associated).

Other Devs will essentially do the source code for the website, assist on the initial deployment of the website to whatever hosting provider the customer has selected and once it's signed off, that's their job done.

I can't tell you what sort of client you are going to attract - whether it's the type that will see value in a fully end-to-end managed solution whereby they pay essentially a retaining fee/maintenance fee for you to manage those additional aspects or whether you are going to attract the type of client who just wants to pay a single cost and be done with it.

I've seen both business models work successfully (as in I've dealt with Devs on multiple occassions using either strategy).

I *personally* found it easier to deal with the Devs that managed everything end-to-end, as they had the access credentials and the knowledge and didn't need to go back to the customer when there was an issue etc.

TL;DR - If you want an ongoing business relationship with each client, go with option 3 - manage it and charge them for it. If you just want to do defined bits of work, Option 2.

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on your infrastructure.

If you have your own servers then you push that angle if everything aligns.

If you don't then you give the client the other options and costs and discuss which fits their needs and budget.

With non technical clients you want full access, they're rarely more than mildly interested in the technical details, they just want it all working yesterday and fixed promptly when things go South.

Either way you factor in your own needs. Do you need a lump sum or a long term revenue trickle? If you have a family to feed often the trickle makes more sense. If not a lump sum to finance a week of whiskey and romance might make more sense. Or both. Is the client even someone you want to do business with long term is another important question.

Comment: week oh whiskey and romance haha. First I've heard that, it's great

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you will not always be a freelance developer.  You might be offered a dream job in Bangkok, or you might be like me, seventy-harumph years old. Or, you might have a falling out with a client; they might quit paying you for example.

You owe it to your clients not to set traps for them.

I have, very successfully, told clients, "Go register a domain name; here's how," and "go sign up for a hosting account; here's how."  You can then manage everything from development onward and charge for it.  When it comes time to move to Bangkok, you can say, "I'm sorry... but I'm outta here. You own the domain name and hosting account for as long as you continue to pay the fees, and stuff should keep working without me.  But... you'll have to find someone else to help you if you need further development or if things fail operationally."